# How do I structure an API that has multiple methods with an Azure Trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-triggers

I have a `[FunctionName]` with a `[HttpTrigger]` in it.

I want my API to have various methods, e.g. `getUserById`, `getAllUsers`, `createUser` etc.

It is unclear if I should be putting them all into a single `HttpTrigger` and using a `switch` statement to work out which method they called and do the logic, or if there is a better way to do it - perhaps with multiple `HttpTrigger` or multiple `FunctionNames` classes.

I don't seem to be able to find anything on google for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I organize a solution with multiple Azure Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992695/how-should-i-organize-a-solution-with-multiple-azure-functions)

Comment: Given the lack of answers, I have voted to close. The question I've marked as duplicate is the closest I've found to an answer for this, although it isn't the 'official' response. It seems that multiple functions within one function app is the way to go.